# Getting relationship from children

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Eloquent, I have a `Category` model that let me define some bank statement categories for my transactions.

A category can either be a parent category, or a child category. All categorized transactions are related to the child category:

```
Leisure
  - Travel
  - Flight
  - Hotel
  - Rental Car
..etc
```

Leisure is a parent category, where the property `category_parent_id` is set to `null`. `Rental Car` is a subcategory with `category_parent_id` set to the ID of `Leisure`. Transactions are related to `Rental Car` and not `Travel`.

I use `parent` and `children` relationship to find a category's children or parent like so:

```php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne( Category::class, 'id', 'category_parent_id' );
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Category::class, 'category_parent_id', 'id' );
}
```

However, if I want to sum up all transactions within a parent category, how can I solve this? The current does not work:

```php
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->children()->with('transactions');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I want to sum up all transactions within a parent category

If what you mean by summing up is combining the transactions of the recursive loaded children, then you would have to keep your `transactions` method as is to load the children recursively and create a separate method to do the combining

Something like this should work:

```
// In your model
public function getCombinedTransactions(){
  $this->load('transactions');
  $transactions = collect();
  foreach($this->transactions as $child){
    $transactions->push($child->getCombinedTransactions());
  }
  return $collection->flatten()->unique('id'); // I'm assuming you want unique by id here
}

// You can call it like this elsewhere
$parent->getCombinedTransactions();
```